# XML: rendered as an HTML file in URL

Tags: html, xml, url, xslt

I've been given the task of rendering an xml file via xsl as html. This means it appears as /.../index.xml in the URL.

However, the task requests that the xml file renders in the URL at /.../index.**html**.

Currently it renders as index.xml not .html - how do I achieve this?

Any ideas/resources would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to satisfy the requirement (there are others, no doubt) is to configure your server to redirect index.html to index.xml.  How you do that depends on which Web server you are using; consult the documentation for your server.  If you're using Apache, you will want to read up on .htaccess files and redirection.

Comment: Thanks, but any configuration of the server isn't allowed. I think it's something to do with the clever manipulation of namespaces or <xsl:output>

Comment: Then you will want to search for the Web to find a way to perform a re-direct from within an HTML document; it's not hard to find.  Nothing you can do with clever manipulation of namespaces or xsl:output in an XSLT stylesheet can cause your Web server or the user's client to run that stylesheet.